# How to show all the Windows partitions on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, wubi, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 with `wubi.exe` installer. It was installed successfully.

But it is now showing two of my windows drives, but not showing other two. I have four in total.

How can I fix this?

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System 
/dev/sda1 63 2047 992+ 42 SFS 
/dev/sda2 * 2048 206847 102400 42 SFS 
/dev/sda3 206848 204802047 102297600 42 SFS 
/dev/sda4 204802048 976771119 385984536 42 SFS
```

Comment: @Lucio sorry. Actually it's showing 2, but not showing other 2

Comment: Please paste the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case -L) from a terminal. If you have dynamic drives (type `sfs`) then that would explain it. Otherwise note that the drive you installed Wubi on is mounted under `/host` (but this doesn't account for the 2 missing partitions)

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   204802047   102297600   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       204802048   976771119   385984536   42  SFS

Answer (score 0):

list drives: `sudo fdisk -l`

list mounted: `sudo mount -l`

mount all: `sudo mount -a`

read more: [MountingWindowsPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)